Issue with Knitting RMarkdown Files After Updating R and RStudio: Error in comment_chars[[engine]] %||% "#"
After installing the new version of R and RStudio, there is an issue with knitting rmd files. I tried to knit even the rmd that appears automatically when you select the creation of a new rmd file in RStudio, but it also shows the error:
processing file: test.Rmd
Error in comment_chars[[engine]] %||% "#" : 
  could not find function "%||%"
Calls: <Anonymous> ... partition_chunk -> <Anonymous> -> get_option_comment
Execution halted

I deleted the old version. I have updated the packages, restarted RStudio and my computer, uninstalled and reinstalled knitr and rmarkdown, but nothing.
Does anyone know any solution?

I ended up fixing it the hard way. I uninstalled R and RStudio, deleted any related folders, and then reinstalled them fresh from the beginning. Everything is working fine now.
